# How to query Active Directory given multiple user names?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to query Active Directory for a single user info

```
public UserInfo FindOne(string samUserName)
{
    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com", "Bob", "pwd"))
    {
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, samUserName))
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                // get info about Alice into userInfo
                return userInfo;
            }
        }   
    }

    return null;
}
```

So if I use `var aliceInfo = search.FindOne("alice");` I get info from the directory. Now I need to search a directory (1000+ users) given several user logon names, for example

```
var userInfos = search.FindMany(/* list of names: alice, jay, harry*/);
```

**How to implement the following method?**

```
public List<UserInfo> FindMany(List<string> samUserNames)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is relatively small, the most flexible solution will probably be to loop and look up the users one by one.

The alternatives are:

- Provide a filter in the LDAP query.  Since you have no common attribute to filter on, you would need to create an "OR" LDAP filter with all of the usernames.  Which doesn't really scale to a large number of users any better than looping.
- Iterate over all users in the directory, filtering the search results to extract the ones that match your list.  This doesn't scale well to a large AD, where it doesn't take advantage of the fact that samAccountName is an indexed property.

Comment: Going to accept this as an answer. There doesn't seem to be any clean API for my case. I am not a big fan of constructing a query string manually and use it with underlying LDAP object. So I've decided to use a single context and loop through the list of users, making individual query to Domain Controller for each user. Additionally I will white list properties that I only need, so each response doesn't come with big bag of satellite data the record happened to store. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string query = "dc=com,dc=domainController,ou=Users"; //this is just an example query, change it to suit your needs

// create your domain context and define the OU container to search in
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourDomain", query);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal (user)
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

return srch.FindAll().Select(p => p as UserPrincipal);
```

This way you can return all users from AD, and then filter out those you don't need. UserPrincipal has a few user related attributes, like Surname and Sid, but if you need to get a value that UserPrincipal doesn't have, you can create an extension method and access any LDAP attribute:

```
    public static String GetProperty(this Principal principal, String property)
    {
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
            return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString() ?? "";
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }
```

Here is a list of LDAP attributes: https://fsuid.fsu.edu/admin/lib/WinADLDAPAttributes.html

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is very slow so doing it like this rather than checking 1 by 1 is going to be better for longer lists but worse for short lists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this going to work in large AD. Transferring all the users using `srch.FindAll()` is unfortunately incredibly slow.

Comment: You can change the LDAP query to get only users you want. You can even filter by names, but if you need to get thousands of users you'll end up with a monster query (I'm not sure if there are any limits on the query size)